# Android - Delay expand of SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, searchview

I want to delay the expand of SearchView. I use a drawerlayout. If the search item is clicked when drawer open, then layout of my views become distorted (a disaster), so I want to close drawer first before expanding search View. Any idea how to achieve this?

I use the following code. I tried to intercept menuitem selected event, triggering drawer to close. And in DrawerListener, call the serchMenu.expandActionView();

I expect the searchView to expand after drawer completed closed, but these two actions always happen simultaneously, and during the transition,  the layout of my views become extremely distorted as well. That why I what delay the expand of search event.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)  mSearchItem.getActionView();
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.search){
        mDarwerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
        mSearchViewShouldExpand = true;

    }
    return true;
}



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
    .......


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDarwerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            0,  
            0 
    ){  

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

            if(mSearchViewShouldExpand){
                mSearchItem.expandActionView();
                mSearchViewShouldExpand = false;
            }
        }

    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDarwerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to intercept expand event, it is in MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener. Just need to return false in this method

```
 @Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

    Log.d("*******","onMenuItemActionExpand");

    mDarwerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

    if(mDarwerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mRightDrawer) || mDarwerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLeftDrawer) ) {
        mDarwerLayout.closeDrawer(mRightDrawer);
        mDarwerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
        mSearchViewShouldExpand = true;
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}
```